# isomorphism between vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

In my book there's a proof of the statement

> $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ span $\mathbb R^n$

Intuitively, two independent vectors in $\mathbb R^3$ span a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. But $(x, y, z) \not \in \mathbb R^2.$ Here's a little discussion of this below:

[Linearly independent vectors spanning lower dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700349/linearly-independent-vectors-spanning-lower-dimensions)

So, does it make sense to say something like $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb R^m$ span a space isomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$  where $m > n$? Where can I look discussions about this and possibly a proof?

Comment: In principle, this is fine, but you need to be careful about what you mean by isomorphism. $\mathbb{R}^n$ has a good deal of structure beyond the vector space structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you're saying does make sense, as long as we are talking about isomorphism of vector spaces.

To construct such an isomorphism, let $\, {v_1,..., v_n}\,$ be $n$ linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R^m}$.

Let $U = span\{v_1, ..., v_n\} \subseteq \mathbb{R^m}$.

Let $f:U \to \mathbb{R^n}$ be the unique linear map sending each $v_i$ to $e_i$ where $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ is the standard basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$.
Clearly this map is invertible, so the two spaces are isomorphic.

In fact, more generally, every two vector spaces of the same dimension (over the same filed of course) are isomorphic.